# How does s% reference the title attribute inside the Helmet component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

Could you help me understand how `%s` is referencing the `<SEO />` component's title attribute inside the `<Helmet />` component in the gatsby starter theme?

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/seo.js

Line 19:

```
titleTemplate={`%s | ${data.site.siteMetadata.title}`}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$s` is inferred from the "title" prop of your  component.

Here is a link to the relevant source code:

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/blob/b79d30ff44c7ff3c175c31059076e5e549a1b402/src/HelmetUtils.js#L27

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `%s` is used to be replaced for `string`:

```js
const str = 'world';
console.log('Hello %s!', str);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I have figured, that it is a string substitution, but I am curious, how %s is referencing the title attribute in gatsby, because unlike in the case of console.log, I can't see the pattern. It may be really obvious, but I just don't see how it works in gatsby.